# Java Android Array Key value

Tags: java, android

There is any data structure in java that i can work like a key value array from php or javascript?

```
$objectKeyTarget = "key2";


$array = array(
    "key1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name" "exemple 1"
    },
    "key2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name" "exemple 2"
    }
);

$dynamicObject = $array[$objectKeyTarget];
```

Comment: [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: You could try using Gson parsar for parsing json like array data and store it in java model list.

Comment: Did you take a look on https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could simply use a `Map` and a `List` for that. I'd suggest something like this:

```java
public class Entry {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  ...
}

Map<String, List<Entry>> entriesByKey = new HashMap<>;
entriesByKey.put("key1", new Entry(1,"exemple 1"));
entriesByKey.put("key2", new Entry(2,"exemple 2"))

Log.d(..., entriesByKey.get("key2"));
```

If you are trying to store a JSON-Respone: There is in-built `JSONObject` in Android, so use that one instead.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way

```js
not_array = {
  'Y':'YES',
  'N':'NO',
  'M': {'MY':'MAYBE YES','MN':'MAYBE NO'}
}
    
value  = 'Y';
result = not_array[value];
console.log(result);

value1  = 'M';
value2  = 'MN';
result1 = not_array[value1][value2];
console.log(result1);
```

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript